# how to pass sql array values from java controller to scala template

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am new to play framework.  I want to pass array variables in java controller to scala template.

```
try {
            String userName = "data";

            String password = "data";

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/playdb";

            // Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
            String strSelect = "select * from computer";

            //statement.setString(1, name);
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);

            while(rset.next()) {   // Move the cursor to the next row
                String name = rset.getString("name");

                int    id   = rset.getInt("id");
                System.out.println( name + ", " + id);
                // ++rowCount;
            }


        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("cant Connected database successfully...");
        }
        Form<Computer> computerForm = form(Computer.class);
      return ok(
        createForm.render(computerForm,rset)
    );
```

and scala templete

```
    @(computerForm: Form[Computer],createFormRset: String)
```

i got the error

```
cannot find symbol [symbol: variable rset] [location: class controllers.Application]
```

I need to pass `rset` value to scala template . But I don't know how please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `rset`outside of your try-block:

```
ResultSet rset = null;
try {
            String userName = "data";

            String password = "data";

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/playdb";

            // Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
            String strSelect = "select * from computer";

            //statement.setString(1, name);
            rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);

            while(rset.next()) {   // Move the cursor to the next row
                String name = rset.getString("name");

                int    id   = rset.getInt("id");
                System.out.println( name + ", " + id);
                // ++rowCount;
            }


        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("cant Connected database successfully...");
        }
        Form<Computer> computerForm = form(Computer.class);
      return ok(
        createForm.render(computerForm,rset)
    );
```

This solution is not really pretty, because if an SQL-Exception occurs, `rset` will be null and you will run into troubles in your template (`NullPinterException`). You might want to consider to move your return statement at the end of the try-block and add another one into the catch block for error handling.

Comment: shall i change anything in template file

Comment: You should change the type of the second variable to ResultSet.

Comment: getting error **not found: type ResultSet** and my template  look like this after i change  **@(message: Array[ResultSet])** i am only passing **rset** value to views

Comment: In the Template: replace `Array[ResultSet]` with `java.sql.ResultSet`. First: You do not pass an array of ResultSet. It is only one ResultSet. Second in the template you do not have the import-statements from the controller.
Further: The Play-framework does not work the way you try to use it. Create a model-class which handles the SQL-stuff. In the controller, get a list/array of your model-class-instances which represent the data. Pass them to the view and display them.
Have a look at the tutorials and examples provided in the play framework documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can pass any java object to the template.  Play framework has type-checking on views so you would have to declare the rset.  If you look at the computer-database sample that comes with Play, you'll see it passes a Page object and three strings:

```
@(currentPage: com.avaje.ebean.Page[Computer], currentSortBy: String, currentOrder: String, currentFilter: String)
```

However, you may find it easier to copy the values from rset into your computerForm object, or another POJO, and pass that to the template.

Comment: its easy when using ebean. but i am using core sql query. i am using try and cach method. so kindly help me how to do this. i am struggling  more than a week for this. no clarification still now