# How to pass array of string values from controller to view

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using the Java Play Framework and trying to pass array values from controller to view, but I got error. My code is here:

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static Result index() {
        String s= "Hello Mr.View";
        String st[] = {"firstValue","second","third","fourth"};
        return ok(index.render(st));
     }
}
```

and my template is:

```
@(message: String)
 @import helper._
    @import models._
    @import java.sql._
              <h1>@message </hl>
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the parameter as a String-Array. I'm assuming you use the default templating system of the framework. It should look something like this:

```
@(message: Array[String])
 @import helper._
    @import models._
    @import java.sql._
              <h1>@message </hl>
```

Comment: thanks its working is it possible to pass sql query values from controller to view.

Comment: Yes this should be possible. Although you might want to consider to pass an array of Strings or an array of of your model-class. The Play Framework suggests to create a model class for your database which handles the queries, etc and provides CRUD functionality. You coud pass Arrays of those objects. (just change the type of the Parameter to `Array[models.YourModel]`

Comment: Kindly see this link here i trying someting with sql in controller i got error i mention here detaild please see the link and help me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590140/how-to-pass-sql-array-values-from-java-controller-to-scala-template/19592030?noredirect=1#19592030